# WooCommerce product until price

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woothemes

I want to create a page in WooCommerce that shows only product untilspecific price.
For example I want to show all products that whose prices not big than 50$.

How i can do this?
Thanks :)

Comment: How exactly would you group your prices? For example, do you want to display all products whose price is $50 or more? And is there a top limit?

Comment: All prodct that price until 50$. The limit is 50$.
I was wrong in my original question, sorry.

Comment: So just to confirm, you need a page which will display your products whose price is between 0$ and 50$?

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved using the following code, by writing custom query:

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged'))? get_query_var('paged') : 1;  
$price_limit = 50;  
$args = array('paged' => $paged, 
              'post_type' => array('product','product_variation') 
              'post-status' =>'publish', 
              'meta_key' => '_price', 
              'meta_query' => array( 
                  array( 
                      'key' => '_price', 
                      'value' => $price_limit
                      'compare' => '<=', 
                       ) 
              ) 
);
$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );

<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?> 
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>    
        <?php //code to represent product list ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?> 
<?php else : ?>
    <?php echo "Data not found"; ?> 
<?php endif; ?>
```

Here, change `$price_limit` value to as per the requirement.

Comment: Where to put this code? i want it to show in new page.
There is some way to do this without using shortcode?